# Star Rating - Not able to reduce value of rating after selecting

Tags: jquery

I am using [this](http://nashio.github.io/star-rating-svg/demo/) jQuery star rating. Once selecting 3.5 if I want to reduce it to 2.5, I am not able to do that.

```
$(".feedback-rating").starRating({
        starSize: 20,
        disableAfterRate:false,
        readOnly:false  });

<div class="rat_blk fl-wrap feedback-rating jq-stars" id="feedback-rating" data-rating="0"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please share with us some code you have written that demonstrates the issue you are facing?

Comment: Updated ques and also add js and css as mentioned in demo link

Comment: There is a bug here. Please check this. https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg/issues/53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug on the plugin.  It works internally but not visually.

Comment below code and you will be fine :

```
if (stateClass === 'rated' && endIndex > -1) { // limit to painting only to rated stars, and specific case for half star if (index <= Math.ceil(endIndex) || (index < 1 && endIndex < 0)) { $polygonLeft.attr('style', 'fill:'+ratedColor); } if (index <= endIndex) { $polygonRight.attr('style', 'fill:'+ratedColor); } }
```

Ref bug [link](https://github.com/nashio/star-rating-svg/issues/53)